# DOM Scraping using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've got a Ruby script for DOM Scraping running Nokogiri gem as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

names = Array.new
contact = Array.new
address = Array.new
final = Array.new
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('INSERTURLHERE')) 

names = doc.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'jcn')]/a/text()").collect {|node| node.strip.text}
contact = doc.xpath("//p[contains(@class,'jrcw')]/a/b/text()").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
address = doc.xpath("//p[contains(@class,'jaid')]/text()").collect {|node| node.text.strip}


final.zip(names, contact, address).each do |names, contact, address|
    puts names + " " + contact + " " + address
end
```

I used command line to run it as

`ruby filename.rb > output.txt`

However, the output.txt is empty. Is there something wrong with the script that's causing it to not run?

Comment: What is printed if you add `puts names`, `puts contact`, `puts address` ?

Comment: @falsetru It prints the names, contact and addresses.

Comment: just as a note you do not generally need to initialize Arrays using the collect method will return an Array so the `Array.new` methods are probably unnecessary. The only time I will initialize an empty array is if I need to append it inside a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final` is an empty array. zipping it with other arrays produces empty array:

```
final = Array.new
final.zip([1], [2]) # <---
# => []

[1].zip([2])
# => [[1, 2]]
```

---

Replace:

```
final.zip(names, contact, address)
```

with

```
names.zip(contact, address)
```